# I am new to php and I need help understanding this code

Tags: php

```
$ep1 = mktime(19,32,56,5,10,1965);

$ep2 = mktime(4,29,11,11,20,1962);
echo($ep2);
$diff_seconds = $ep1 - $ep2;

$diff_weeks = floor($diff_seconds/604800); // 128 
*$diff_seconds -= $diff_weeks * 604800;

$diff_days = floor($diff_seconds/86400);
*$diff_seconds -= $diff_days * 86400;


$diff_hrs = floor($diff_seconds/3600);
*$diff_seconds -= $diff_hrs * 3600;

$diff_mins = floor($diff_seconds/60);
*$diff_seconds -= $diff_mins * 60;
echo('<br>');
echo("Difference = $diff_weeks,$diff_days,$diff_hrs,$diff_mins");
```

I want to understand why the lines marked with an asterisks(*) has been done?
Thank you

Comment: What exactly do you not understand about those lines?

Comment: `$diff_seconds -= $diff_hrs * 3600;` translates to : `$diff_seconds = $diff_seconds -  $diff_hrs * 3600;`

Comment: I don't get why do we minus the $diff_seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start the other way round.
Say you want to express the timespan (3 days) + (17 hours) + (47 minutes) + 13 seconds in seconds. That would be (without leap seconds et al)

```
(3*86400) + (17*3600) + (47*60) + 13
= 259200 + 61200 + 2820 13
= 323233 (=$diff_seconds)
```

Now let's take a look what the script does ( we skip the weeks and start with the days)

```
$diff_days = floor($diff_seconds/86400);
= floor(323233/86400);
= floor(3,7...);
= 3

$diff_seconds -= $diff_days * 86400;
$diff_days * 86400 = 259200 <-- see? That's the first factor in (3*86400) + (17*3600) + (47*60) + 13
```

those 259200 have already "been handled", so they are subtracted from the the seconds that are still to be processed. After that $diff_seconds only counts the seconds that can't be expressed as days (as integer).
The next step handles all seconds that can be expressed as (integer) hours and again subtracts them from the remaining seconds and so on and on.

Comment: He is sequentially getting the remainders, left after division

Answer (score 1):

Those are [Assignment operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php), here is a list of all [operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php) in php.

Comment: I think OP wants an explanation of the lines marked with an asterisk. Not what the asterisk does.

Comment: -= is an assignment operator though, I'll update the question with that as an example.

Comment: @putvande piddl0r is not explaining the asterisk here, he's explaining the *assignment operator* on those lines.

Comment: @piddl0r- I do understand those are assignment operators but I want to know why $diff_seconds is subtracted?